# create a dynamic title that displays date range as per the start and enddate parameters used

Tags: date, reporting-services, range, display

I have a report that displays monthly and ytd amounts. I use start and enddate parameters that change according to the user. For example for startdate 4/1/2007 and enddate 2/28/2008
1. I need to display title as Monthly budget 2/1/2008 to 2/28/2008
2. I need to display title for YTD as YTD 4/1/2007 to 2/28/2008

I tried = Parameter!EndDate.value but it throws error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have missed a letter in your expression. It should be:

```
=Parameters!EndDate.Value
```

In the expression editor you can double click on the parameter name and it will insert it into the expression for you.

To get the full description that you mentioned, you'll need to use a combination of functions. One useful one to look at is `DateAdd` to add days and months to the specified date. Another one is `FormatDateTime` which allows you to use the standard "ShortDate" format.

If you run into further trouble, I would recommend posting a new question with the variations of code that you tried along with the specific error messages that you received.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the Expression for a text box to:

```
="Monthly Budget " & FORMAT(Paramters!StartDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & " to " & "FORMAT(Paramters!EndDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

This will give you:

```
Monthly Budget 02/01/2008 to 02/28/2008
```

It is the same for your second requirement, just change the wording.